# Heat Capacity in Mean Field Theory

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, mean-field-theory

I have been very confused with calculating the heat capacity when dealing with a Mean Field Hamiltonian.

The Hamiltonian I am working with describes a spin lattice of fermions in 2D. I only count the nearest neighbor interactions.
When I apply the mean field theory, of course I end up with the magnetization $(m=\frac{1}{N} <S_i>)$ in my Hamiltonian.

When I calculate the self consistency equation for the magnetization, I get something like:
$m=tanh(\beta m J)$
Where $\beta=\frac{1}{kT}$ and J is just the combined coupling between the spins.

Now here is where I struggle.
When calculating the specific heat I came across several definitions, which without MFT are always equal to each other, but in MFT just get really messy.

For example $C=\beta^{2} \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial \beta^{2}} ln(Z_{MFT})$.
But $Z_{MFT}$ contains m which itself is also dependent on $\beta$.
Because $\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial \beta^{2}}$ is a partial derivative, I would assume I do not derive m with respect to b. But for example when I use the definition $C=\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}$ where $U=<H_{MFT}>$ I have to also derive m with respect to T, even though it is a partial derivate, because otherwise the two definitions do not become equal.

I have also come across a masters thesis, where they used the definition
$C=\beta^{2} \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial \beta^{2}} ln(Z_{MFT})$
and proceeded to derive also m in respect of $\beta$ and of course ended up with terms $\frac{\partial^{2} m}{\partial \beta^{2}}$.
In another calculation, they used the definition $C=\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}$.
When I try to replicate their result using the $C=\beta^{2} \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial \beta^{2}} ln(Z_{MFT})$ definition I just can not get it right.

Of course, it could just be a simple mistake in my calculations, especially because using the first definition gives a much more elegant calculation, but at this point I am just very confused and unsure about my understanding about these definitions.

There is probably a really trivial explanation to my question, but at this point I just can not wrap my head around this problem, so I would be very grateful if somebody could help me understand this.
Thanks!

Comment: Who is $b$, could you please clarify? What exactly do you try to reproduce? By definition, $C_V=(\partial U/\partial T)_V$. But you can compute $U$ via the partition function as $U=T^2(\partial \ln\mathcal{Z}/\partial T)$

Comment: You may find useful my answer to this related question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/644431/correlations-in-ising-mean-field-theory/683717#683717

Comment: Sorry, stupid mistake. The b was supposed to be a $\beta$ as well. I edited the question.

Comment: So regarding my attempts to reproduce the results of a masters thesis: They calculated the heat capacity using the definition $C=\frac{\partial U_{MFT}}{\partial T}$. I have been trying to replicate their result for $C$ using the definition $C=\beta^{2}\frac{\partial^{2} ln(Z_{MFT})}{\partial \beta^{2}}$, which should also be equal to $C=T^{2}\frac{\partial^{2} ln(Z_{MFT})}{\partial T^{2}}$. But it does not reproduce the same result. But that could just be a mistake in my calculations. I hope that helps, sorry that this is so long.

Comment: @artem-alexandrov I hope my comments cleared things up?

Comment: @Roger for me it still unclear what do you want to reproduce. Do you mean $C=C(T)$ near $T_c$?

Comment: @ArtemAlexandrov So in the thesis they calculated $C=\frac{\partial U_{MFT}}{\partial T}=Expression_1$. What I was trying to achieve is getting $Expression_1$ as the result of calculating $C=\beta^{2}\frac{\partial^{2}ln(Z_{MFT}}{\partial \beta^{2}}$ (where $Z_{MFT}$ is a specific partition function), which would then verify that the formulae $C=\beta^{2}\frac{\partial^{2}ln(Z_{MFT}}{\partial \beta^{2}}=\frac{\partial U_{MFT}}{\partial T}$ are equal also in MFT.